# Running ffmpeg on cmd works, but integrating it with PHP gives out an error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ffmpeg, video-processing

Running ffmpeg to covert files to mp4 works normally when ran from a command line prompt, but
upon trying to integrate it into a php code I keep getting errors and I am not sure why that is. The error says:

```
'-i' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Upload failed
```

This is the function that is responsible for running ffmpeg code that converts the file:

```
  public function convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath) {
    $cmd = "$this->ffmpegPath -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1";

    $outputLog = array();
    exec($cmd, $outputLog, $returnCode);

    if($returnCode != 0) {
        //Command failed
        foreach($outputLog as $line) {
            echo $line . "<br>";
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and since my code is returning an error pointing to a command line command being faulty, I am guessing it is triggering the  `echo $line . "<br>";` from the function above.
However, right under this error output, I have an error `Upload failed`
which points to a different function in the program, mainly the one responsible for the upload of the file itself:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($videoData["tmp_name"], $tempFilePath)) {
        $finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".mp4";

        if(!$this->insertVideoData($videoUploadData, $finalFilePath)) {
            echo "Insert query failed\n";
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath)) {
            echo "Upload failed\n";
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->deleteFile($tempFilePath)) {
            echo "Upload failed\n";
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->generateThumbnails($finalFilePath)) {
            echo "Upload failed - could not generate thumbnails\n";
            return false;
        }

    }
```

But even though I get the output saying Upload failed, my file DOES get transfered into the folder that is dedicated as the "Upload folder" but the file is **NOT** converted from flv to mp4 before being uploaded, so I am left very confused.

For those who are wondering what the whole code looks like, this is VideoProcessor.php :

```
<?php
class VideoProcessor {

    private $con;
    private $sizeLimit = 500000000;
    private $allowedTypes = array("mp4", "flv", "webm", "mkv", "vob", "ogv", "ogg", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "mpeg", "mpg");

    private $ffmpegPath;

    private $ffprobePath;

    public function __construct($con) {
        $this->con = $con;
        $this->ffmpegPath = realpath("C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg");
        $this->ffprobePath = realpath("C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe");

    }

    public function upload($videoUploadData) {

        $targetDir = "uploads/videos/";
        $videoData = $videoUploadData->videoDataArray;

        $tempFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . basename($videoData["name"]);
        $tempFilePath = str_replace(" ", "_", $tempFilePath);

        $isValidData = $this->processData($videoData, $tempFilePath);

        if(!$isValidData) {
            return false;
        }

        if(move_uploaded_file($videoData["tmp_name"], $tempFilePath)) {
            $finalFilePath = $targetDir . uniqid() . ".mp4";

            if(!$this->insertVideoData($videoUploadData, $finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Insert query failed\n";
                return false;
            }

            if(!$this->convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Upload failed\n";
                return false;
            }

            if(!$this->deleteFile($tempFilePath)) {
                echo "Upload failed\n";
                return false;
            }

            if(!$this->generateThumbnails($finalFilePath)) {
                echo "Upload failed - could not generate thumbnails\n";
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    private function processData($videoData, $filePath) {
        $videoType = pathInfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(!$this->isValidSize($videoData)) {
            echo "File too large. Can't be more than " . $this->sizeLimit . " bytes";
            return false;
        }
        else if(!$this->isValidType($videoType)) {
            echo "Invalid file type";
            return false;
        }
        else if($this->hasError($videoData)) {
            echo "Error code: " . $videoData["error"];
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function isValidSize($data) {
        return $data["size"] <= $this->sizeLimit;
    }

    private function isValidType($type) {
        $lowercased = strtolower($type);
        return in_array($lowercased, $this->allowedTypes);
    }

    private function hasError($data) {
        return $data["error"] != 0;
    }

    private function insertVideoData($uploadData, $filePath) {
        $query = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO videos(title, uploadedBy, description, privacy, category, filePath)
                                        VALUES(:title, :uploadedBy, :description, :privacy, :category, :filePath)");

        $query->bindParam(":title", $uploadData->title);
        $query->bindParam(":uploadedBy", $uploadData->uploadedBy);
        $query->bindParam(":description", $uploadData->description);
        $query->bindParam(":privacy", $uploadData->privacy);
        $query->bindParam(":category", $uploadData->category);
        $query->bindParam(":filePath", $filePath);

        return $query->execute();
    }

    public function convertVideoToMp4($tempFilePath, $finalFilePath) {
        $cmd = "$this->ffmpegPath -i $tempFilePath $finalFilePath 2>&1";

        $outputLog = array();
        exec($cmd, $outputLog, $returnCode);

        if($returnCode != 0) {
            //Command failed
            foreach($outputLog as $line) {
                echo $line . "<br>";
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function deleteFile($filePath) {
        if(!unlink($filePath)) {
            echo "Could not delete file\n";
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function generateThumbnails($filePath) {

        $thumbnailSize = "210x118";
        $numThumbnails = 3;
        $pathToThumbnail = "uploads/videos/thumbnails";

        $duration = $this->getVideoDuration($filePath);

        echo "duration: $duration";
    }

    private function getVideoDuration($filePath) {
        return shell_exec("$this->ffprobePath -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 $filePath");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check what the full command it's trying to execute is `echo $cmd;`.

Comment: could you elaborate further @NigelRen

Comment: What does `$cmd` contain before you try and run it?

Comment: Try changing to single quotes around the paths in your `realpath()`. Example: `realpath('C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg')`. The problem is that when you're using double quotes, some character combinations like `\f` will be read as [control characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) and won't be read "as is". Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/g36W7. So when `realpath()` gets that incorrect path, it will return "false", which means that your command will start with just `-i`

Comment: @M.Eriksson just to let you know. I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Does "didn't work" mean you got the exact same error, or did the error change while still not working? However, there might be more issues. As @NigelRen already asked, what does the variable `$cmd` contain before you execute it? Just do an echo or var_dump() on that variable and check it. We don't have access to your system so we can't debug your code for you.

Comment: @M.Eriksson it gave the same error. as far as the var_dump goes, Im not sure how to run var_dump() before the exec is ran

Comment: How about `var_dump($cmd);` right before your `exec()`? A simple `echo $cmd;` should also do the trick.

Comment: @M.Eriksson after putting var_dump($cmd); into a line before executing it, now it outputs this: 
'string(164) " -i uploads/videos/62a465e23b64dY2Mate.is_-_JOSIPA_LISAC_-_When_a_man_loves_a_woman_(1968.)-ftKgvB6ZJ7Q-480p-1653046433338.mp4 uploads/videos/62a465e23b83a.mp4 2>&1" '-i' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Upload failed '

Comment: Then do: `var_dump($this->ffmpegPath);`. If it contains `false`, then the path to ffmpeg is still invalid and you need to sort that out

Comment: @M.Eriksson indeed it does return:

bool(false) '-i' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Upload failed 

but how can a path be false, I literally copied and pasted the ffmpeg path

Comment: To sanity check things, as @M.Eriksson said you need single quotes (`'`) not double quotes (`"`) for strings where you are using unescaped backslashes. Have you changed them over too?